# How to create Firebase users with Google Sign-In and React Native App using Expo Go

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, google-signin

I am using Expo Go to develop a React Native application. The user authentication is being handled with Firebase Auth. I want to provide an option to register with Google. The [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) suggest implementing this with a popup which does not work in a native application. I have found several other sources that outline how to do this in react native, but all of them seem to suggest that it is not possible with Expo Go.

Can someone point me in the right direction if I want to continue using Expo Go? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get firebase google auth working through Expo Go using Expo SDK 47. With the release of Expo SDK 48 in February 2023, I believe it is no longer possible to get it working with Expo Go. See explanation of the SDK 48 updates [here](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-48-ccb8302e231). You could of course, continue using Expo SDK 47 with Expo Go for as long as SDK 47 is supported, but I wouldn't recommend that since they updated due to a security issue.

I was reluctant to migrate to Expo Dev Clients, but it went smoother than anticipated, so I would recommend biting the bullet and moving forward with Expo Dev Client. I believe you will need a paid apple developer account to create the builds. The other issue I'm having with this method, is that I cannot seem to get the authentication flow working in a preview build, although it works fine in the development build. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76030003/google-login-working-in-development-build-but-not-preview-build) which has my code sample embedded, which works with the development build.

Comment: I appreciate your response and agree with you. I was able to get Expo Go working with v47 and also found that the auth flow only worked on a dev build. I have still been developing in v47 but based on your response will likely try to upgrade to 48. I'm a web developer so all this native stuff has me going crazy lol

Comment: Interesting... There must be a way to get it working with the preview build. I'll let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: I solved my issue and now have it working in all builds. I had changed my project name at some point during development, so my expo project name no longer aligned with my bundle id. I created a new expo project with the new name, added my secrets to the expo project, re-configured the build, created a new "preview" build and voila! It works smoothly in both the dev build and the preview build.

Comment: awesome! Do you outline this in more detail anywhere else?

Comment: I haven't. I originally followed this youtube tutorial to learn how to get firebase and expo set up together:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJaFIGjyRms . But that video uses the previous version of expo, so you need to use a different bundle identifier as described in the documentation of the expo SDK 48 update. That in combination with my code sample would in theory be sufficient enough to get a sample working. I should probably write a medium article or do a youtube tutorial or something showing the process end-to-end though, cause there are a lot of places where you could go wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll give it a shot this weekend and see how it goes